# В чем может быть проблема?

Tags: php

**index.php**

```
<?
include('/header.php');
include('/main.php');
include('/footer.php');
?>
```

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/xz/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    </head>
```

**main.php**

```
    <body>

    </body>
```

**footer.php**

```
</html>
```

Как бороться вот с этим

[image: img]

P.S. кодировка стоит utf-8

Comment: в разметке, я сказал вам уже... используйте валидатор.

вы вообще в курсе что у вас там путь абсолютный в include, удивительно что хоть как-то работает.

проверьте что у вас до <? ничего нет (какой-то utf8-BOM бывает в недоосях)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если используете notepad++, экспериментируйте с разными версиями utf-8 -> uft-8 as ANSI.
Если notepad++ под рукой нет (macos, linux), можно через hex editor вручную удалить байты 
"отвечающие" за BOM. Многие посоветуют воспользоваться утилитой iconv - тоже вариант (там десятки кодировок и одних только utf  больше 10 штук).
Если проблема останется, выкладывайте все эти файлы, будем разбираться.

Совет: не оставляйте подобные вопросы не решенными, это очень мелкие проблемы, и только решив ВСЕ мелкие Вы сможете решать серьезные задачи.

Comment: C исходным кодом уже все норм. Разобрался. Но вот теперь:

![img](http://i.imgur.com/iv4JTMh.png)

Comment: Когда возникают проблемы с кодировками в первую очередь проверяют (для utf-8):
1) файл в корне .htaccess должен иметь строку AddDefaultCharset utf-8
2) страхуемся и пишем в html: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
3) кракозяборный файл должен быть в utf-8. Это может показать notepad++.

Этого достаточно. Но также можно экспериментировать с отдачей заголовков напрямую. Для этого есть php-функция header(), но ей пользуйтесь только когда понимаете в каких случаях и для чего она нужна.